# Limitations of Ω-Spectra

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectra

Right now I am interested in the "stabilization" endofunctor of the category of ∞-groupoids sending an object $X$ to $\text{colim } Ωⁿ Σⁿ X$. This colimit is related to $∃Y:X≅ΩY$. In Ω-spectra, this proposition is true.

I was trying to figure out why there are so many variations in categories of spectra and read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrum_(topology)#Technical_complexities_with_spectra) about five properties one might like of a category of spectra that were altogether impossible. I was wondering specifically what the case is for Ω-spectra along with its adjunction with CW-complexes. What properties does this lack and what are some selling points of these other longer definitions of spectra?

Comment: Sequential spectra don't have a functorial point-set smash product.

Comment: @JHF is there any advantage in requiring that Xₙ  ≅ΩX${}_{n+1}$ only on πₖ for k ≤ n?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind, and you could always convert a sequential spectrum into a $\Omega$-spectrum via a telescope construction.

Comment: @JHF I just thought it could be easier to construct the smash product since the next one only needs "one more degree" of accuracy.